# How to search in all modules that match a particular pattern in intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, module

Assume that we loaded in IDEA a project that has multiple modules. Is there any way to do a global search (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>) in all modules that match a particular pattern in name?

For example:

[image]

I want to search the desired keyword only in the modules that contain `client` in the name: `client-side-filtering` and `client-side-validation`. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom scope:

1. Open `Find in Path`
2. Click on the `Scope` button below the search text field
3. Click on the `...` button
4. Click on the `+` button in the `Scopes` dialog that appears, and select `Local`
5. Enter a name, for example "Client modules"
6. Enter the pattern `file[client*]:*/` in the pattern text field
7. Click `OK` to search in the scope you have just created.